# How to prove that $x(2\pi-x)$ is an even function when $ 0 \le x \le 2 \pi $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fourier-series

I'm trying to find the Fourier Coefficients for $ x\cdot(2\pi-x) \rightarrow 0 \le x \le 2\pi $.
This task is an easy one..

$$ a_0=\frac{4}{3}\pi^2 $$
$$ a_n = -\frac{4}{n^2} $$
$$ b_n = 0 $$

So where is my problem? The task is an exercise from a book and the solution says that f(x) was even so $b_n = 0$ but I'm not able to prove that.

A function is even when $ f(-x) = f(x) $. Usually I would do something like f(-3) = f(3). But this doesn't work here. 
For example: $ f(3)=9,85; f(-3)=-27,85 $.
Furthermore when I plot the function it doesn't look very symmetric either.

Comment: Periodic continuation.

Comment: Your title does not match your question. If $f (x)= x(2\pi - x) \; [x \in [0,2\pi]]$, then it is even. But for $x(\pi -x)$, it is not.

Comment: Sorry, typo... But how to mathematically prove this? Am I right that f(-x) = -f(x) doesn't work here or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: $f$ is even iff $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x$, not $f(-x) = -f(x)$, which is $\color{red}{\mathrm{odd}}$.

Comment: oh my... yes you're right. But it doesn't solve my problem. I updated the question.

Comment: So how did you calculate $f(-3)$?

Comment: (-3)*(2Pi-(-3)) = -3*(2Pi+3) = -27,85

Comment: No, that's not the case. Fourier series applies to **periodic functions**. When we are given the function on a specific interval, it is implied that we are dealing a function with period equals the length of the interval and the restriction of this periodic function to the given interval is the function given. Check your textbook if you have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fourier series applies to **periodic functions**. When we are given the function on a specific interval, it is implied that we are dealing with a function whose period equals the length of the interval [in your case, $2\pi$] and the restriction of this periodic function to the given interval is the function given [in your case, $x(2\pi -x)$ on [$0, 2\pi$]]. Check your textbook if you have one.

As I said, if you $2\pi$-periodically continue the function $f$ to $F$ on the whole axis $\mathbb R$, then clearly this $F$ is even [by observing the graph, or check the equation $F(x) = F(-x)$ for all $x$].

**UPDATE**

Compute the expression of the function $F$. Example. For $x \in [-2\pi, 0]$, $x + 2\pi \in[0, 2\pi]$. Since $F(x) = F(x+2\pi)$ for $x \in [-2\pi, 0]$, we have 
$$
F(x) = (x +2\pi) (2\pi - (x + 2\pi)) = -x (x+2\pi). 
$$

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense that when I periodically continue this parabola it's symmetric. But I'm stuck at the F(x) = F(-x). How can I represent that periodic function as a formula (because obviously using $ x(2 \Pi -x) $ is wrong). Sorry for being so pedantic but I'm feeling that I'm missing something here.

Comment: See my update. The expression at other points could be derived similarly.

Comment: I just plotted your function and it seems not quite right. Here is the plot: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bx+(2+Pi+%2B+x),+%7Bx,+-2+Pi,+0%7D%5D 
I calculated it by myself and got f(x)=x(-x-2Pi).    
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bx+(-2+Pi+-+x),+%7Bx,+-2+Pi,+0%7D%5D

Comment: @TimSch Yes. I missed a minus sign. Thanks for warning.